# Memory Allocation in C++

Tags: c++, memory

Does the memory allocated by class pointers get freed by the class destructor once the class method/function goes out of scope? Or do I need to manually free the memory allocated by the pointer (C++). 
For example, here's a snippet of some simple code :

```
double * const  Area()
{
  double * Area = new double;
  *Area = itslength*itswidth;
  return Area;
  //itslength and itswidth are private class variables
}
```

So in this example, do I have to free the memory allocated by the Area 
 pointer, or does the class destructor do this by default once the function returns/goes out of scope? If I have to manually free memory, can you modify my code to free the memory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization

Comment: The memory allocated by `new` is on the heap and is not freed automatically upon return. The caller will have to `delete` it. The memory use by the pointer (the address) is freed upon return, like all local variables.

Comment: As a side note: Your code is very hard to read - you are e.g. creating a `double*` local member which has the same (identical) name as the function is is defined in. Do your codevelopers (and your future self) a favor by following some basic naming conventions (which ones exactly is a question of personal preferences, you could e.g. use [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#General_Naming_Rules) as a starting point and pick&choose the ones you find useful/sensible/good)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things allocated using `new` are not automatically deleted.  There needs to be a corresponding `delete` somewhere in your code.  This can be very error-prone and is best avoided.

If you must use `new` and `delete`, try to adopt an RAII approach - the `new` can only appear in a constructor, and the corresponding destructor always has the matching `delete`.

If you want a collection of things, use one of the standard C++ collection classes, as they tidy up behind themselves - but take great care with collections of pointers, as you still need to delete the things being pointed to.

Alternatively, various pointer management classes have been added to C++ over the years, which do tidy up behind themselves.  See the answer by xtofl.

Answer (score 3):

When you're starting with C++, shun away from anything telling you to use `new`.  You most probably do not need it.

Memory management is very error prone, and has been solved by more modern approaches.  Look up "[value semantics](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics)" and RAII.  And only when you *really* need dynamically allocated memory, find out what `std::unique_ptr<double>` can do for you.

For the function you wrote, no dynamic memory is needed:

```
auto area() {
  return itslength * itswidth;
}
```

And finally: yes: the *destructors* of all the object's member variables are called after the object's destructor has been called.